# App data - String array or XML : performance and memory

Tags: android, android-activity

I am making Android app, I have to use multidimensional data, either in String [][] or in Xml resource file. Please suggest which one is better from performance perspective and memory used in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

As Jack stated, the operations on a `String[][]` would probably have better performance than working with an XML file.  It would also likely have a smaller memory footprint.  Depending on what sort of data you are dealing with, a `String[][]` might be cumbersome to deal with.  If the data is hierarchical, I would go with an XML file for simplicity.

If you thing an XML file is the way to go, take a look at [this](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html) article on parsing XML in Android.  The article claims that an [XmlPullParser](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html) is "efficient."

You may want to consider using a JSON format as third option :)

Answer (score 0):

If you only care about the performance and memory footprint, `String[][]` would be better.

But place your data into xml and access them as resource has its advantages.

Following is quoted from Android developer's document.

> Using app resources makes it easy to update various characteristics of your app without modifying code and—by providing sets of alternative resources—enables you to optimize your app for a variety of device configurations (such as different languages and screen sizes).

In addition, by zip aligning the resources, the resource can be mapped to memory which makes the speed to access them also very fast.